# How can I add an additional field for a Woocommerce download file?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The question has arisen, how can I add an additional field for the downloadable Woocommerce file? Unfortunately, for some reason I couldn’t find a solution or any plugin for this on the Internet. Maybe someone has encountered this problem before?

Here is a screenshot of where you need to add a custom field:

[image]

Comment: When you make a screenshot make it in English, by changing temporarilly the language for your user...

Comment: Short answer is you can't. The only available hook is woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data - https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_file/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-general-php/

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin to add a custom Field to a product. That could be a easy solution für you.

**ACF**
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

**Add custom fields to WooCommerce Products using ACF**
https://www.commercegurus.com/woocommerce-acf/

Maybe that's a starting point for you.

Best
Gregor